# Does switching user account in Ubuntu 18.04 affects the on going work?

Tags: user-accounts, ubuntu-18.04

One of the c++ codes is running in one user account, what will happen if I change the user account? Will the code in my previous user account be still running or it will stop working?

Comment: What kind of code? How is it running? Have you tried it?

Comment: OP said it's C++ code

Comment: @music2myear c++ based simulation code (ns3 to be specific) is currently running for more than 24 hours by now. I want to switch accounts (graphically), but not sure what will happen.